# Replacing Macbook Pro SSD with Macbook Air SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd

Currently I have a Macbook Pro (mid 2014) with 120GB ssd. I am planning to buy a Macbook Air (say, early 2015) with 250GB ssd and swap these drives between laptops. I know they are both PCI based, but that doesn't mean much
as the protocol could be SATA/NVM/Proprietary.

My concerns are:
1. Will it work?
2. Should I expect significant performance differences between these drives?

I checked compatible drives for both laptops on ifixit:
https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/MacBook-Air-11-Inch-and-13-Inch-Mid-2013-to-Early-2015-and-MacBook-Pro-Retina-13-Inch-and-15-Inch-2015-SSD/IF188-105-5 Air

https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-and-15-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Mid-2014-SSD/IF123-026 Pro

I see that Air's SSD is compatible with Air models from 2013 to 2015, but with Pro models only of 2015 -- that seems weird and I expect that it's just a misleading description. Does anyone have such (successful or not) experience?

Comment: For what reason are you swapping the drives out? If you planing on using the newer computer it wouldn’t make sense to but an old SSD inside of it. It would make more sense to get an external drive and use it as a backup disk. Then on the new computer just restore the backup

Comment: @MatthewN Initially I was planning to buy a new ssd, but I figured that buying a used Air in perfect condition won't cost too much more and my wife could use a light laptop (:

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Matthew.
MBA early 2015 connector PCLE 8GT/s
MBP mid 2014 connector PCLE 5GT/s.
I suppose it can be done, but I would not do it at all.
You have to reinstall everything including the EFi and RecoveryPartitions, otherwise it will not work at all.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.  Keep in mind that Ask Different is a Q&A site, not a *forum* for conversation.  I encourage you to review  [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Well, of course I'll have to wipe the drive and reinstall macOS. But that doesn't seem to be much of an issue.